# Homomorphism between the Field F and the Quotient Ring of Polynomial Ring

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, extension-field

I'd like to show for a field $F$ and ideal $I$, the mapping $\phi: F \rightarrow F[x]/I$ defined by $\phi(a)=a+I$ is a ring homomorphism.

Showing $\phi(a+b)=\phi(a)+\phi(b)$ is rather straightforward. We have

$$\phi(a+b) = (a+b)+I = (a + I)+(b+I) \text{ (by properties of Ideals)} $$
$$\phi(a)+\phi(b)$$

For the second part, I need to show $\phi(ab) = \phi(a)\phi(b)$. This is where I am not sure how to proceed. Probably there is a property of ideals that I am forgetting:

$$\phi(ab)=(ab)+I$$

Can I simply conclude from this that $(ab)+I=(a+I)(b+I)$, which is what I need to complete the proof?

Also, in this proof I am not really using the fact that co-domain is $F[x]/I$. Is that normal?

Comment: You need to show _why_ $(ab)+I = (a+I)(b+I)$; this should be another exercise in using the rules of an ideal. Consider what a 'typical' element of $(a+I)(b+I)$ looks like.

Comment: I see, so writing $(ab) + I = (a + I)(b + I)$ is fine.

Comment: The product in the quotient ring is simply defined as $(a+I)(b+I)=ab+I$. There is nothing to prove here. (obviously it has to be checked that it is well defined, but I assume you already know that)

Comment: right, right! I forgot that. In that case, the proof above seems very trivial, makes me wonder if I am missing something.

Comment: It's the composition of the inclusion $F\to F[X]$ and the projection $F[X]\to F[X]/I$. Compositions of homomorphisms are homomorphisms.